# suggestion of videos youtubeapi remove android studio

Tags: android-studio, youtube-api

alguien sabe como quitar  los  videos sugeridos de youtubeapi o videos relacionados,  al finalizar el video me salte videos sugeridos. en la documentación no encuentro ese parametro...

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer
        youTubePlayer, boolean restaured) {


youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(style);
youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
youTubePlayer.loadVideo(id_channel);
```

** en web  vi que usan  rel 0 y 1 para quitar eso. dentro de un frame,  pero  yo uso la  apiyoutube traigo el jsonlist y las  id  de mis videos...

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente en la clase YoutubePlayer no existe una forma de deshabilitar los elementos relacionados, de hecho posiblemente no sea implementado, ya que esto implica más vistas a su contenido.

La clase no contiene un método para este proposito:

```
public interface YouTubePlayer {
    int FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION = 1;
    int FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI = 2;
    int FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE = 4;
    int FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT = 8;

    void release();

    void cueVideo(String var1);

    void cueVideo(String var1, int var2);

    void loadVideo(String var1);

    void loadVideo(String var1, int var2);

    void cuePlaylist(String var1);

    void cuePlaylist(String var1, int var2, int var3);

    void loadPlaylist(String var1);

    void loadPlaylist(String var1, int var2, int var3);

    void cueVideos(List<String> var1);

    void cueVideos(List<String> var1, int var2, int var3);

    void loadVideos(List<String> var1);

    void loadVideos(List<String> var1, int var2, int var3);

    void play();

    void pause();

    boolean isPlaying();

    boolean hasNext();

    boolean hasPrevious();

    void next();

    void previous();

    int getCurrentTimeMillis();

    int getDurationMillis();

    void seekToMillis(int var1);

    void seekRelativeMillis(int var1);

    void setFullscreen(boolean var1);

    void setOnFullscreenListener(YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener var1);

    void setFullscreenControlFlags(int var1);

    int getFullscreenControlFlags();

    void addFullscreenControlFlag(int var1);

    void setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle var1);

    void setShowFullscreenButton(boolean var1);

    void setManageAudioFocus(boolean var1);

    void setPlaylistEventListener(YouTubePlayer.PlaylistEventListener var1);

    void setPlayerStateChangeListener(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener var1);

    void setPlaybackEventListener(YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener var1);

    public static enum ErrorReason {
        /** @deprecated */
        EMBEDDING_DISABLED,
        /** @deprecated */
        BLOCKED_FOR_APP,
        NOT_PLAYABLE,
        NETWORK_ERROR,
        UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY,
        PLAYER_VIEW_TOO_SMALL,
        PLAYER_VIEW_NOT_VISIBLE,
        EMPTY_PLAYLIST,
        AUTOPLAY_DISABLED,
        USER_DECLINED_RESTRICTED_CONTENT,
        USER_DECLINED_HIGH_BANDWIDTH,
        UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION,
        INTERNAL_ERROR,
        UNKNOWN;

        private ErrorReason() {
        }
    }

    public static enum PlayerStyle {
        DEFAULT,
        MINIMAL,
        CHROMELESS;

        private PlayerStyle() {
        }
    }

    public interface OnFullscreenListener {
        void onFullscreen(boolean var1);
    }

    public interface PlaybackEventListener {
        void onPlaying();

        void onPaused();

        void onStopped();

        void onBuffering(boolean var1);

        void onSeekTo(int var1);
    }

    public interface PlayerStateChangeListener {
        void onLoading();

        void onLoaded(String var1);

        void onAdStarted();

        void onVideoStarted();

        void onVideoEnded();

        void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason var1);
    }

    public interface PlaylistEventListener {
        void onPrevious();

        void onNext();

        void onPlaylistEnded();
    }

    public interface OnInitializedListener {
        void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider var1, YouTubePlayer var2, boolean var3);

        void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider var1, YouTubeInitializationResult var2);
    }

    public interface Provider {
        void initialize(String var1, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener var2);
    }
}
```

---

La única opción es usar el player embebido en un WebView y agregar la propiedad `rel`:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0"
  frameborder="0"/>
```

> **rel** : Valores: 0 o 1. El valor predeterminado es 1. Este parámetro indica si el reproductor debe mostrar videos relacionados al finalizar
>   la reproducción del video inicial.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

Comment: cuando lo llamas  con frames perdes  el ListApi de YoutubeApi...   por eso no se puede usar  rel, tmb que  hay hacer el GET a la APi te trae  id de youtube video

Comment: si lo deseas realizar mediante YouTubePlayer API definitivamente no tiene un método expuesto para lo que deseas, la única forma es usar una ´página en un WebView.